# Can the word "bikini" refer to the bottom part of the bikini swimsuit?

Tags: meaning

The Oxford dictionary gives only two meanings for the word "bikini": the atoll and the 2-piece swimsuit. But I think that sometimes this word refers to the underpants only and not the entire suit. Is it a correct use or am I missing something?

Comment: In American English we have the phrase "bikini pants/panties". We would not understand "bikini" to refer to the bottom alone.

Comment: I call the bottom half a 'bikini bottom'.  Obviously the other piece is a 'bikini top'.  (British English)

Comment: The style of the swimsuit bottom is used to make underwear called *bikini briefs* as well.

Comment: Why the downvote? It is an interesting question, it has brought about an interesting discussion and the OP provided their reasoning.

Comment: Not my downvote, but rather than just making a supposition, your question should include where you saw such usage. If you just want to know what it is called, again it needs to be in the question.

Comment: For what it is worth, we can say: *look that woman is wearing a bikini but only the bottom part/piece*.

Comment: I think that sometimes this word _bikini_ refers to naked women only and does not refer to a swimsuit at all. Is it correct please or i am missing something!? :)

Comment: @AmD I'm not familiar with the usage of bikini to refer to an unclothed woman, just to the swimsuit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are only talking about swimsuits, the most widespread term (at least in the US) is bikini bottom. Bikini tops and bottoms can be sold separately, but they are considered pieces of one outfit, similar to shirts and pants. If you use the plural "bikinis" with a singular subject, it does refer to just the bottoms. For a feminine subject, it almost always refers to bikini panties, but for a man it might be unclear whether it was a swimsuit or underwear depending on the dialect.

Some folks refer to male bikini style swimsuits as "speedos", the most popular brand of that style in the past. The [Speedos USA site](http://www.speedousa.com/mens-competition-swimwear?style=briefs) refers to that style as "briefs", not bikinis. Thinking about it, I hang out with a group of folks that's pretty diverse when it comes to [gender identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_identity) and sexual orientation, so "briefs" might be much more mainstream than "bikinis".

Depending on the context, it can be ambiguous for women as to whether you're referring to the panties or to both pieces of the swimsuit. For example, "She wore bikinis every day." could be interpreted either way. Most online stores have a "bikinis" category of women's underwear, while the male category is usually ["bikini briefs"](http://amzn.com/B005CW06XC).

Bikini bottoms on swimsuits have a certain shape of leg hole. There are [other styles swimsuit of bottoms](http://www.landsend.com/shop/womens-swimsuits/-/N-fxmZk9fZk9pZk9t?cm_re=nav-_-women-_-featureshop-_-swimshop).

If you say "The girl was wearing a bikini." it will be assumed that she was wearing both pieces of a bikini swimsuit. If you say "The woman was wearing a bikini bottom.", it's unclear what type of top she might or might not have been wearing, but it will be clear what sort of pants she had on. If you are talking about a man wearing bikini bottoms, you can just say "bikinis". For example, "Most of the men were wearing swim trunks, but Joe was wearing bikinis." If you say "Joe was wearing a bikini", some folks might get a picture of a man wearing both pieces of a women's bikini.

[Monokinis](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1615&bih=1336&q=Monokini&oq=Monokini&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1974.3262.0.3517.8.8.0.0.0.0.226.857.0j5j1.6.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..2.6.854.yWrSnQpxtvU) these days (in the US at least) are one piece swimsuits that cover both top and bottom, but are more revealing than a typical one piece swimsuit and intended to be very sexy. A regular one-piece swimsuit that is styled to be useful for swimming instead of laying on the beach looking sexy is usually called a "tank" swimsuit.

Comment: Can you provide the link please to instances of using the plural bikinis only as the bottoms?

Comment: I will see if I can find one @AmD It's one of those things that's just so commonly used in my dialect that I haven't thought about it. It's definitely informal, if not bordering on slang.

Comment: After some poking around, I found a lot of ladies clothing stores with an underwear section refer to them as "bikinis", but had some trouble finding written text or captions that weren't really inappropriate. Some things you just can't un-see :( @AmD

Comment: I really doubt that someone among women and girls would use _a bikini_ or _bikinis_ to refer only to panties or the bottom part of a swimsuit!@ColleenV

Comment: Well, I do. The folks around me do.  Why is it so strange to call bikini style panties, bikinis?  Yes, it's informal, and can be ambiguous taken out of context, but it's not uncommon to shorten terms when speaking. You've probably haven't been subjected to too many lengthy discussions about the cuteness/price/fit of various styles of panties or you might not be so doubtful ;) @AmD

Comment: @AmD Maybe a comparison will help. If I say "She was wearing a thong." you will probably think of the underwear. If I say "She was wearing a bikini." you will picture her in a swimsuit. If I say "She was wearing bikini bottoms." you will picture her in one part of a two piece swimsuit. If I say "She was wearing bikinis, not briefs." the common understanding in my dialect is she wore bikini style panties, not multiple swimsuits.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom part of a bikini, when worn on its own, would be a:

[monokini](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/monokini):

> A woman’s one-piece beach garment equivalent to the lower half of a bikini. (ODO)

Although the swimsuit [bikini](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bikini) was named after the island and has nothing to do with a prefix [bi-](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bi-) meaning "two" (but rather with the explosive effect the swimsuit produced when it first appeared, according do ODO), *monokini* was a convenient way to distinguish between the two types of bathing suits. According to dictionaries the name *monokini* emerged as a misinterpretation of *bi* in *bikini*, but one can't help wondering whether someone in the 60s had a good sense of humour and made a pun that became a regular word.

Comment: Have you ever heard this word used?  It feels like a slang word that got picked up by the ODO somehow and then lost.  Perhaps it's used in BrE?

Comment: @JasonPatterson I must have heard (or more likely read) it somewhere, because it was the first word that came to mind when I read the question, and I looked it up to provide a reference. [MW unabridged version](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monokini) also lists the word (unfortunately, I have limited access to that one) and so does [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/monokini). It seems that today it is used for one-piece swimsuits as well, but the dictionaries still don't recognise such usage (P.S. non-native speaker here)

Comment: A reputable source that uses the word might be: Striptease: The Untold History of the Girlie Show by Rachel Shteir, published by: Oxford University Press, USA, 2004. "But the fashion development that led directly to topless dancing was the monokini" [...] "The New York City police threatened to arrest any woman wearing a monokini and fine her for indecent exposure"

Comment: It's not commonly used in BrE.  We say 'bikini bottom'.

Comment: Yes but the great answer by @ColleenV appears to discuss a different meaning of *monokini* than you and the ODO are talking about. Okay, I just read your comment wherein you acknowledge this. Your answer might be more complete with this info in it.

Comment: @pazzo I think monokini in common usage has evolved from when the term was first coined.  Going topless on a beach is still not a social norm in the US, and I think the swimsuit sellers co-opted the word for marketing purposes.  I don't think monokini is very widespread outside the folks that are very interested in fashion. I wouldn't look at the images in the search I linked and immediately think monokini.

Comment: FWIW, the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/121447) gives three quotations of _monokini_ to mean a topless bathing suit from 1964 and one from 1974, and includes this note in the etymology: "French _monokini_ and _bikini_ were both apparently coined by Louis Reard and patented by him in 1946: see _Femmes d'Aujourd'hui_ (1972) 12 July." Their wording suggests that mono/bikini was an intentional pun (in French, and the pun also works in English). I think that today, though, _monokini_ is commonly understood as in ColleenV's answer.